# Flexbox non-sibling grandchildren

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's [an example](http://jsbin.com/xafoji/edit) of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically I want a DOM structure like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grandchild flex-3">
      Wide Grandchild
    </div>
    <div class="grandchild flex-1">
      Narrow Grandchild
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grandchild flex-2">
      Medium Grandchild
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want the grandchildren's flex properties to be reflected as if they were siblings.

Here's the CSS I have currently:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.grandchild {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 6px;
  border: solid 2px #ddd;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-2 {
  flex: 2;
}

.flex-3 {
  flex: 3;
}
```

I want it to render like this:

[image]

However, it's rendering like this:

[image]

Comment: I got it working using [this solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/EpGsggVIxBJSF8V7tMyh?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it to look like what you're aiming for. I have updated your [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tuvazasaye/2/edit).

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child-flex flex-2">
    <div class="grandchild flex-3">
      Wide Grandchild
    </div>
    <div class="grandchild flex-1">
      Narrow Grandchild
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child child-flex flex-1">
    <div class="grandchild flex-2">
      Medium Grandchild
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution I went with. I'm using angular and can calculate the flex width of the grandchildren and apply the sum of the grandchildren to the child. Works great.